# Are my Spring Boot entities normalised if not How can I do so?

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

I have a table having a oneToMany relation with another table

```
 public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Books.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId",
            referencedColumnName = "userId",
            updatable = true,
            insertable = true)
    private List<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

where my Books entity is

```
public class Books {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String bookName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double bookPrice;
}
```

My entities:

[image]

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XHq7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XHq7.png)]

I can have different prices for the same book for different users.

Are my entities normalised?

If not what changes I can make?

Comment: To me this looks like more of a many-to-many relationship, not a one-to-many. You need to record the same book multiple times for every user.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "normalised" here & how/where are you stuck, following what process, having done what? [ask] [help] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach look good but i have one suggestion for you, don't use `FetchType.Eager` for more details please read next ones articles how to avoid it and why it's not a good ideea to use it.

[FetchType.Eager code smell](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/)

[Hibernate 6 guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html) **read about eager fetch type**

Comment: look good, but in your case many-to-many is better.

Comment: because, one user can have more than one book and also one book cand have multiple users